# Can I use two associative entities in a ternary relationship?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-relationship

[image: ERD Image]

For example,

1. I have Job as one entity which has a relationship with Customer. This makes one associative entity (say, Service).
2. I have another associative entity between Job and Employees (say, Workforce).

Can I create a ternary relationship between Job (Entity), Service (Associative Entity 1) and Workforce (Associative Entity 2)?

Comment: You should add the code for your entities and their relation as well as what you've tried so far to get a higher chance for an answer.

Comment: "Can I...?" In 95% of cases, yes.